# The "in" preposition is missing translation in the "new users" tab of ru.SO

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

In the "new users" tab of ru.SO, "in" is not translated.

> [image]

Also, if sorting by days, "in one day" is also in English:

> [image]

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] =)

Comment: Aaaand now it's really completed. )

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл наконец-то!

Используются следующие строки:

[Tx:6489-6491](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/42116519?q=%24Reputation%24%20in%20%24MemberFor%24)

> $Reputation$ in $MemberFor$
>   $Reputation$ за $MemberFor$

И эти:

[Tx:6492-6494](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/42116522?q=%24Reputation%24%20in%20one%20day)

> $Reputation$ in one day
>   $Reputation$ репутации за день